# Writing to Text File

Tags: java

So I'm using this function to write to text file, but the text file always ends up empty after executing. Can anyone see what the error might be? I've been stuck on this for a while.

```
public static void writeTextFile(String fileName, String s) {
    FileWriter output = null;
    try {
      output = new FileWriter(fileName);
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);
      writer.write(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
      if (output != null) {
        try {
          output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // Ignore issues during closing
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: You are not closing bufferwriter!!add this code writer.close()

Comment: I believe you need to use output.flush(); output.close(); methods http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

After writing your output you should make sure to [flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) and close the socket, specially because you are using a buffered output.

```
writer.write(s);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

If you don't do that, the BufferedWriter will wait for additional data, but there does come none and the program execution is stopped suddenly. **Using flush here is optional**, as when closing it the flush is implicit, but personally I call it everytime I need to be sure that something goes out. Just like when on the toilet ;)

Comment: There's no need to call `flush()` explicitly - `close()` is guaranteed to flush the writer.

Comment: @Mureinik that's what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your to include `writer.close();`  as given below

```
 try {
      output = new FileWriter(fileName);
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);
      writer.write(s);
      writer.close();
    }
//remaining code
```

The reason your data not saved in the file because , The Data is saved only if you call `writer.flush();` And calling the `writer.flush()` method is enough to just save data. But you need to close the BufferedWriter() like `writer.close();` to avoid resource leak. The `close()` calls `flush()` method for you before closing the stream.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Buffer to write something, you must close him when you re end

```
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without closing bufferwriter you cannot see output on text file
try to add this code

```
 writer.close()
```

Comment: reason behind the negative rep for all the answers????

Comment: probably the not rated guy wanting to get to the top ;)